# Translate one line from C# to C?

Tags: c#, c

I have never used C# before and Im trying to translate a function to C and all was going well until I reached this weird line. Someone help?

```
out Int128 remainder;

remainder._lo |= 1; ???
```

Comment: Are you sure it's C#? it doesn't look that way

Comment: I'm not really familiar with C#, but if I were a bettin' man, I'd guess that's just setting the least significant bit of a 128 integer.

Comment: I've only ever seen "out" used in parameter declarations and if you're saying the value type Int128 has a property that can have the OR operator applied to it, then perhaps I don't know C# as well as I thought I did...

Comment: And since it's Int128, you can't convert it directly, because it is a BigInteger. You should use an array to save all bytes.

Comment: MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx - if you need it.

Comment: @RobbieDee - `_lo` is probably a field, not a property.

Comment: Fields are more properly defined as properties these days with lazy instantiation etc but yes, I take your point that the underscore would rather indicate a member variable rather than a property...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the equivalent of

```
remainder._lo = remainder._lo | 1;
```

where `|` is the bitwise or operator, but the `|=` shouldbe aupported in C as-is.

`Int128` is presumably a structure with `_hi` and `_lo` members to store the high and low 64 bits of the 128-bit integer.  This line is just doing a bit-wise or of the low 64 bits with 1, effectively switching on the least significant bit.

Answer (score 4):

assuming in C you have an Int128 struct of the same nature...  in C it would be

```
remainder._lo |= 1;
```

which just says do a bitwise OR with 1

Some C compilers provide a 128bit ints you could use, in which case you'd end up just doing `remainder |= 1;`

Answer (score 4):

This implies that

```
remainder._lo
```

is an integer of some type, and the |= operator is bitwise or.

So this is equivalent to

```
reminder._lo = reminder._lo | 1
```

That might be legal C depending on your context, but that should give you the key to it.